# Creating internal functions (can't be called from console) in R

Tags: r

I'm working on an R package where I have an overarching function that generates some files, we'll call it `main(...)` and it exists in its own file `main.R`. Now `main` calls other functions like `helper1(...)` and `helper2(...)` which are found in `helper1.R` and `helper2.R`. Is it possible to make it so that `main` can call the helper functions, but the user cannot call directly the helper functions? I have them spread out in different files due to the stark differences in their purpose. Is the solution to put them all under one file `main.R`?

Comment: Yes, read about [namespaces](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) and deciding which functions in your package to export.

Comment: So my NAMESPACE file should have the line `export(main)` but not `export(helper1)`, etc.? Right now it just matches on regex which I believe is  the default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham.

What you want <del>is</del> *should be* the default behaviour for packages: you have exported and non-exported functions. Unless you explicitly declare a function as exported, it is invisible to the outside and only usable by other functions inside the package.

So you don’t need to do anything for the helper functions. You do, however, need to mark the `main` function as exported.

Comment: So as @joran mentioned, I need to change in my NAMESPACE what to export. Default is `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`; but if I line by line list each function to export, and exclude `helper1` and `helper2`, they can exist in their own file but not be exported?

Comment: @TomNash that depends on how the `NAMESPACE` file was generated. It *should be empty* by default but it’s true that R’s `package.skeleton` function generates a non-empty `NAMESPACE` file. It’s a good idea to delete everything in it to start with. At any rate, you shouldn’t ever touch that file yourself, use devtools and let the file be autogenerated (the link in my answer explains how).

Comment: @TomNash One of the things that many people like about Hadley's package development style is that you end up using roxygen2 to document your functions and this lets you specify which functions to export in the file with the function, and roxygen2 builds the NAMESPACE file for you.

Comment: I see, `roxygen2` seems pretty powerful for making markdowns and exporting functions. Think I'm squared away now.