# How to access internal functions not exported from a package?

Tags: r

Hi I'm working with the `DaMiRseq` package and one of the functions is hanging without error so I'm trying to investigate it. When I do `View ( classify)` and follow it leads to an internal function call `classify.continous` which is not exported but I would like to view this on rstudio if possible so that I can see what the issue is.  Is there a way to do this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817099/how-to-use-internal-functions-of-a-given-package-in-my-own-functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091361/creating-internal-functions-cant-be-called-from-console-in-r  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359115/how-to-load-packages-internal-function-in-global-environment

Comment: @NadPat thanks, that works, ::: is the way, should delete I this post?

Comment: Decision is on you :-)